# How to have 2 collections of the same type in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, persistence

I've got 2 entities in JPA: Entry and Comment. Entry contains two collections of Comment objects.

```
@Entity
public class Entry {
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexColumn(base = 1, name = "dnr")
    private List<Comment> descriptionComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexColumn(base = 1, name = "pmnr")
    private List<Comment> postMortemComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    ...
}
```

To store such objects, JPA+Hibernate creates "Entry" table, "Comment" table and SINGLE "Entry_Comment":

`create table Entry_Comment (Entry_id integer not null, postMortemComments_id integer not null, pmnr integer not null, descriptionComments_id integer not null, dnr integer not null, primary key (Entry_id, dnr), unique (descriptionComments_id), unique (postMortemComments_id))`

Storing of objects fail as `descriptionComments_id` and `postMortemComments_id` cannot be "not null" at the same time.

How do I store object containing two collections of the same type using JPA+Hibernate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one of the many Hibernate bugs ([HHH-3410](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3410) to be precise).

I've managed to fix it by adding `@JoinTable` annotations to `@OneToMany` relationships, each having its own table name.

In your case it would look like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="entity_descriptioncomments")
@IndexColumn(base = 1, name = "dnr")
private List<Comment> descriptionComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="entity_postmortemcomments")
@IndexColumn(base = 1, name = "pmnr")
private List<Comment> postMortemComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
```

**Note**: you must add `@IndexColumn` annotation as well (because of the other Hibernate issue with multiple EAGER bags: [HHH-1718](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1718)/[EJB-346](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/EJB-346)).

Comment: And how do u make this relationship bidirectional ?

Answer (score 4):

To store 2 collections like that in JPA with *DataNucleus* (http://www.datanucleus.org) you would do exactly as you've done. You have no `@JoinTable` annotation hence a FK should be placed in `Comment` for each of the collections. If you actually do have `@JoinTable` somewhere (or XML equivalent) then setting the names of the respective join tables (one for each collection) would work too (so they have their own join table). Having a shared join table between 2 collections is possible in DataNucleus too, but that's not standard JPA, instead a vendor extension.

How that maps to Hibernate I've no idea, but then this is JPA so should be consistent since thats the point of having a spec ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a flaw with current mapping from data model/domain model point of view: you actaully have a **single** *@OneToMany* relationship between *Entry* and *Comment*. And *Comment* entity should have one more attribute called *type* that takes 2 values: '*description*' or '*postMortem*'.

To be inline with your current implementation of *Entry* entity you may want to consider breaking down *Comment* entity into 2 different entities (possibly using JPA inheritance features) and using *@JoinTable* annotation in *Entry*.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is ordering, how about configuring the two index column definitions to have the same name?