# How to have 2 collections of the same type in JPA? (EclipseLink)

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Wondering how to do what is specified in [How to have 2 collections of the same type in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669828/how-to-have-2-collections-of-the-same-type-in-jpa), but with EclipseLink rather than Hibernate. See that post below:

> I've got 2 entities in JPA: Entry and
>   Comment. Entry contains two
>   collections of Comment objects.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@IndexColumn(base = 1, name = "dnr")
private List<Comment> descriptionComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@IndexColumn(base = 1, name = "pmnr")
private List<Comment> postMortemComments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
```

> To store such objects, JPA+Hibernate
>   creates "Entry" table, "Comment" table
>   and SINGLE "Entry_Comment":
>
> create table Entry_Comment (Entry_id
>   integer not null,
>   postMortemComments_id integer not
>   null, pmnr integer not null,
>   descriptionComments_id integer not
>   null, dnr integer not null, primary
>   key (Entry_id, dnr), unique
>   (descriptionComments_id), unique
>   (postMortemComments_id))
>
> Storing of objects fail as
>   descriptionComments_id and
>   postMortemComments_id cannot be "not
>   null" at the same time.
>
> How do I store object containing two
>   collections of the same type using
>   JPA+Hibernate?

I am sure it is pretty simple to convert that solution to EclipseLink, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the names of the join tables by `@JoinTable`